# IllegalModelException: Namespace is not defined for type org.acme.airline.aircraft.Aircraft

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am following a Udemy tutorial on Hyperledger fabric. **I want to import a model file(or a namespace) to another model file**. But I am receiving an error.

```
IllegalModelException: Namespace is not defined for type org.acme.airline.aircraft.Aircraft
```

I want to import *org.acme.airline.aircraft* to *org.acme.airline.flight*.

The two files are : -

```
> 1. org.acme.airline.flight.cto
> 
>     namespace org.acme.airline.flight
>     
>     import org.acme.airline.aircraft.Aircraft
>     
>     asset Flight identified by flightNumber {
>       o String  flightNumber
>       o Route route
>       o String[] aliasFlightNumber
>       --> Aircraft aircraft optional
>     }
>     
>     concept Route {
>       o String origin
>       o String destination
>       o DateTime schedule
>     }
```

2. org.acme.airline.aircraft

> ```
> namespace org.acme.airline.aircraft
>
>   asset Aircraft identified by aircraftId {
>   o String aircraftId
>   o Ownership ownershiptType default="LEASED"
>
>       o Integer firstClassSeats
>       o Integer businessClassSeats
>       o Integer economyClassSeats
>       o String nickName optional
>
>     }
>
>     enum Ownership {
>       o LEASED
>       o OWNED
>     }
> ```

I tried to remove the permissions.acl file as suggested in one of the little-related questions on StackOverflow, but it the error still persists.

In the permission.acl i am receiving an error that,

```
IllegalModelException: Failed to find namespace test.*
```

Answer (score 1):

click on here for one of the solution [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-vscode-plugin/issues/52).
It says that: Currently, to work with models that use imports and span multiple files, **you must open all related files**. To validate the ACL files and query files, the corresponding model files must also be opened as well. I plan to improve this by allowing a folder to be opened, but from what you say, it sounds like it is working as designed.